# How does C++ handle cleanup of pointers passed as arguments?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, arguments

I've been doing some research on how C++ handles pointers passed as arguments, but haven't been able to find a solid 'yes/no' answer to my question so far.

Do I need to call delete/free on them, or is C++ smart enough to clear those on it's own?

I've never seen anyone call delete on passed pointers, so I'd assume that you don't need to, but I'd like to know if anyone knows any situations when doing it is actually required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The storage used for pointers passed as arguments will be cleaned up.  But the memory that they point to will not be cleaned up.

So, for instance:

```
void foo(int *p)  // p is a copy here
{
    return;
    // The memory used to hold p is cleared up,
    // but not the memory used to hold *p
}

int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    foo(p);   // A copy of p is passed to the function (but not a copy of *p)
}
```

You will often hear people talk about "on the heap" and "on the stack".<sup>*</sup>  Local variables (e.g. arguments) are stored on the stack, which is automatically cleaned up.  Data allocated using `new` (or `malloc`) is stored on the heap, which is not automatically cleaned up.

---

<sub>* However, the C++ standard doesn't talk about "stack" and "heap" (these are actually implementation-specific details).  It uses the terminology "automatic storage" and "allocated storage", respectively.</sub>

Comment: Awesome, that's kind of what I thought. Thanks very much for the quick response!

Comment: In retrospect, I realize my question is pretty dumb... the pointer would just be cleared on the stack when the function exits, but the actual data being pointed to would remain on the heap. Thanks again!

Comment: @PhilElm: That's what resource managing classes are for. C++ does not have `malloc/free` style memory management.

Answer (score 4):

Arguments passed to a method are stored on the stack, therefore are automatically destroyed when the function returns - just as local variables. The memory where they point to is not automatically free-ed.

Answer (score 2):

If you receive a pointer from your caller, it's the *caller*'s responsibility to free that pointer, unless documented otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

On the pointers themselves, no.  They go when the parameter stack frame is eliminated upon the function return, just like int or char parameters.  Whether you have to do anything with the data pointed to is between you and your code..

Answer (score 1):

Pointers will be copied - accepted "by value". When the function exists they will be destroyed but because their destructors are trivial nothing will be done to the memory they point to.